# What is the best way to go with quarter panel repair?

Tags: rust, restoration, welding

I’m working on my first DIY car restoration project. Of course the car had a lot of rust spots I needed to fix. After a lot of practice and learning, I started with floor panels and underbody repairs to gain some confidence in this type of welding and sheet metal work.

Now that the underbody work is nearly done, I need to move on to the quarter panels. I want to achieve the best possible results both aesthetically and functionally. Therefore I’m looking for a best approach. The situation is depicted on the image below.

[image]

What I’m planning to do is to:

1. cut out the rusty part and trim the patch panel to size
2. prepare the area and patch panel for lap welding using the flange/punch pliers
3. tack the patch panel in
4. do a series of plug and short lap welds to give it enough strength
5. fill the rest of the “lap”
6. grind, paint, undercoat, wax… etc.

I’m especially worried about filling the rest of the “lap”. I’ve seen that some people just MIG weld it completely, but I don’t think this is necessary, and I think it puts a lot of heat and stress into the parts. Another option is to just use body filler, which I’m not a huge fan of neither (its how one of my previous cars was fixed by a respectable shop and it started cracking after one or two years).

I’ve seen an interesting method of “TIG brazing” where you fill the gaps using CuSi3 or similar filler rods, without putting a lot of heat into the workpiece, nor actually melting the base metal. It is also being used in automotive and even motorbike frame fabrication, so it seems this might be the best way not to screw it up and make it durable for years to come. I’m afraid of the galvanic/electrolytic rust though, since steel and the filler rod are different metal.

I live in a rust belt and the car is going to be used for daily driving (even though I’ll try to avoid driving on salty roads, sometimes it will happen).

What are your suggestions? Do you think my plan (including the TIG brazing method) is good?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!